# the default MaxInlineSize for java methods is 35 bytes of bytecode

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jvm, jvm-arguments, jvm-hotspot

I am starting to develop with google app engine.

Does google change the default size of *MaxInlineSize* ? Can I set jvm options with google app engine ?

Looked in the obvious place, could not find an answer : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/

**edit**

App engine questions never attract much attention.

Comment: You are *starting* to develop with google app engine and the first question is about a performance tuning parameter? Why do you think it has any relevance for your software which has not even written yet? [It’s rather unlikely that it does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18741113/2711488)

Answer (score 0):

No, I believe you don't have any control over how GAE starts the virtual machines.

I think your best option if you want to control this would be the managed VMs:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/

Quoting:

> Note: Managed VMs will also support custom user-configurable custom runtimes very soon.

Comment: are the settings used by app engine listed anywhere, like the MaxInlineSize for example ?

Comment: I never found them listed publicly. I guess they don't want users to depend on configuration so they can change it internally if they seem to fit better.