# Will the Java compiler optimize out String.length() in a for-loop's condition?

Tags: java

Consider the following Java code fragment:

```
String buffer = "...";
for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(buffer.charAt(i));
}
```

Since `String` is immutable and `buffer` is not reassigned within the loop, will the Java compiler be smart enough to optimize away the `buffer.length()` call in the for loop's condition? For example, would it emit byte code equivalent to the following, where `buffer.length()` is assigned to a variable, and that variable is used in the loop condition? I have read that some languages like C# do this type of optimization.

```
String buffer = "...";
int length = buffer.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(buffer.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Java (and in .Net), strings are length counted (number of UTF-16 code points), so finding the length is a simple operation.

The compiler (`javac`) may or may not perform [hoisting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion), but the JVM JIT Compiler will [almost certainly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073025/java-jit-method-inlining) inline the call to `.length()`, making `buffer.length()` nothing more than a memory access.

Comment: What about really long Strings, let's say a few 1000K?

Comment: It's `O(1)` cost, so it doesn't matter.  The string is stored as `{ length = 1000, character data = { 0x65, ... 0x65 } }`.

Comment: I think he is talking about the JIT (Just in time compiler) with jitter

Comment: @Drejc: No matter how long it is, the `String` knows its own length without counting. (It has to, because there's no way to count. Unlike in (say) C, where strings are terminated by `\0`, in Java there is no way to determine the length of a string by examining the character contents.)

Comment: Incidentally, Mitch, `length` is the number of UTF-16 code units (`char`s), so, not exactly "byte counted". (A string of length `3` has three `char`s, which is six bytes.) But, +1 anyway, since this is a minor point.

Comment: Java is a platform which specifies a virtual machine for its execution.  The compiler takes the source code and generates java bytecode, which is then translated to machine code (x86, arm thumb, etc...) by the Just In Time compiler (aka JIT).

Comment: @Mitch: so the bottom line is that it's ok to leave in `buffer.length()` in the loop condition because it's a memory read (due to the function being inlined)?

Comment: The bottom line is that unless profiling has identified something as being a problem, I wouldn't sacrifice readability for potential speed.  "programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute" ~H. Abelson

Answer (score 2):

The Java compiler (`javac`) performs no such optimization.  The JIT compiler will likely inline the `length()` method, which at the very least would avoid the overhead of a method call.

Depending on which JDK you're running, the `length()` method itself likely returns a final `length` field, which is a cheap memory access, or the length of the string's internal `char[]` array.  In the latter case, the array's length is constant, and the array reference is presumably `final`, so the JIT may be sophisticated enough to record the length once in a temporary as you suggest.  However, that sort of thing is an implementation detail.  Unless you control every machine that your code will run on, you shouldn't make too many any assumptions about which JVM it will run on, or which optimizations it will perform.

As to how you should write your code, calling `length()` directly in the loop condition is a common code pattern, and benefits from readability.  I'd keep things simple and let the JIT optimizer do its job, unless you're in a critical code path that has demonstrated performance issues, and you have likewise demonstrated that such a micro-optimization is worthwhile.

Comment: "JIT compiler will likely inline the length() method". Any documentation on this? I love to read about this sort of stuff.

Comment: It actually doesn't return the length of the `char[]`, since the `String` might only use part of it. `String`s have their own `final int` field to remember the length.

Comment: By default, I believe the Oracle JVM will inline up to 35 **bytes** of bytecode for a method that has been called at least once.  I believe there is a larger threshold for frequently-called methods.  You might check [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737774/hotspot-jit-inlining-strategy-top-down-or-down-top).  @resueman, the version of the source I'm looking at doesn't have a separate field.  Yet another example of assumptions we should not make about the client machine's JVM/JDK :).

Comment: @resueman String array sharing has been gone at least since Java 7. It was indeed implemented this way, but thats a thing of the ancient past. Java7/8 use a private array, with exactly the length in chars.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Interesting. I'd thought every implementation was handling it that way. The openjdk-7 docs do. Definitely goes to show that you shouldn't trust in details like that unless you have complete control over the environment :)

Comment: @MikeStrobel, you seem to have a good means of accessing source.  Is there a website you use or do you have it checked out locally?

Comment: @Mitch The sources for the public/portable JDK classes ship with the JDK.  I imagine most IDEs are capable of navigating to those sources just as you would jump to a type declared within your project.  IntelliJ handles it quite seamlessly: just Ctrl+Click on a `String` type identifier, or hit Ctrl+N and type `String`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, hmm.  Learn something new about my IDE every day..., thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do several things to examine the two variations of your implementation.

1. (difficulty: easy) Make a test and measure the speed under similar conditions for each version of the code. Make sure you loop is significant enough to notice a difference, it is possible that there is none.
2. (difficulty: medium) Examine the bytecode with javap and see how the compiler has interpreted both versions (this might differ depending on javac implementation) or it might not (when the behavior was specified in the spec and left no room for interpretation by the implementor).
3. (difficulty: hard) Examine the JIT output of both versions with JITWatch, you will need to have a very good understanding of bytecode and assembler.