# Best of static method and non static method

Tags: java, static

I have Util classes where i have many methods to be used in all over project.
My question is - considering memory heap, performance what is best to use a static method by class reference or non static method called by object of that class. For example:

```
public class Utilities {

    private static Utilities utils;

    public static Utilities getInstance() {
        if (utils == null)
            utils = new Utilities();
        return utils;
    }

    public static void someMethod() {

    }

    public void someMethod2() {

    }

}
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Utilities.someMethod();
    Utilities.getInstance().someMethod2();
}
```

Which is correct way for my requirement?

Comment: There's no major *contract*-related difference. You just need to consider unit testing for caller classes (harder with static methods). Otherwise, it comes down to preference (static imports, etc.)

Comment: What you showed here looks like "singleton vs static context". In that case this should be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12367609, [When is Singleton appropriate?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/252)

Comment: @Ernest Sorry, i didn't get you clearly, is this same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't matter unless you have a very specific goal in mind. Class or method declaration format can be tweaked e.g.:

- Small method can potentially be inlined by JIT (explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18741113/1602555)).
- Classes might be defined with extra fields to prevent false sharing (explained in ["Our solution - magic cache line padding" paragraph in this article](https://mechanitis.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/dissecting-disruptor-why-its-so-fast_22.html)).

It would make sense to ensure that methods in the most critical section of your application are inlined but this matter only if your application is CPU-bound. A single call to an external resource e.g. database query will be in orders of magnitude more expensive that local code.

The code should be redable before you start optimizing it. `static` methods are much harder to unit test so they probably should be avoided if they contain significant logic that requires unit testing.

Comment: So singleton pattern is preferable?

Comment: Or a dependency injection framework like [Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework). Some people consider singleton an anti-pattern but rolling out DI framework in a simple application might be an overkill.